# How to iterate through multidimensional array with PHP & save as JSON/BSON?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, active-directory, ldap

I have this piece of code, feel free to skip to the bottom of the code where I'm trying to iterate through the array, I left the entire code so that it can be used for testing purposes.

```
<?php

//Saves all the attributes of all entries into an array.
function cleanUpEntry( $entry ) {
  $retEntry = array();
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $entry["count"]; $i++ ) {
    if (is_array($entry[$i])) {
      $subtree = $entry[$i];
      //This condition should be superfluous so just take the recursive call
      //adapted to your situation in order to increase perf.
      if ( ! empty($subtree['dn']) and ! isset($retEntry[$subtree['dn']])) {
        $retEntry[$subtree['dn']] = cleanUpEntry($subtree);
      }
      else {
        $retEntry[] = cleanUpEntry($subtree);
      }
    }
    else {
      $attribute = $entry[$i];
      if ( $entry[$attribute]['count'] == 1 ) {
        $retEntry[$attribute] = $entry[$attribute][0];
      } else {
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $entry[$attribute]['count']; $j++ ) {
          $retEntry[$attribute][] = $entry[$attribute][$j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $retEntry;
}

  $ldaprdn = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
  $ldappass ="password";
  $ldapuri = "ldap.forumsys.com";

  // Connecting to LDAP
  $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapuri)
          or die("That LDAP-URI was not parseable");

  //We need to set the LDAP Protocol Version or else it isn't able to bind properly to the LDAP server.
  ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

  ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
  //We bind to the LDAP server using the previous credentials and location.
  $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

  // Verify if bind was successful or not
  if ($ldapbind) {
      echo "LDAP bind successful...\n";
  } else {
      echo "LDAP bind failed...\n";
  }
  //Gives where to search & what to search for
  $dn = "dc=example,dc=com";
  $filter = "(objectclass=*)";

  //Saves the result into result variable
  $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter);

  $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

  $header = array_fill_keys($headers, null);
  $output = [];


  //Gets the search results and saves into details variable.
  $details = cleanUpEntry($info);

  print_r($details);


  //HERE'S MY ISSUE: The array isn't being iterated through properly.
  foreach ( $details as $name => $entry ){
    echo "\nName: " . $name . "\n";
    if(is_array($entry)){
      foreach (array_keys($entry) as $array_key => $value)
        //echo "Entry: " . $array_key . ":" . $value . "\n";
        echo $value . "\n";
        //This foreach doesn't work.
        /*foreach ($value as $key1 => $value2){
          echo $key1.":".$value;
        }*/
    }else{
      foreach($entry as $key => $value){
        echo $key . ":" . $value . "\n";
      }
      //echo "Entry: " . $entry . "\n";
    }
  }

?>
```

Here's what the array looks like, I left most of the elements out, but you can see the whole array if you copy my original code above:

```
Array
(
    [dc=example,dc=com] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => dcObject
                    [2] => organization
                )

            [o] => example.com
            [dc] => example
        )

    [cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => simpleSecurityObject
                    [1] => organizationalRole
                )

            [cn] => admin
            [description] => LDAP administrator
        )

    [uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com] => Array
        (
            [sn] => Newton
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => inetOrgPerson
                    [1] => organizationalPerson
                    [2] => person
                    [3] => top
                )

            [uid] => newton
            [mail] => newton@ldap.forumsys.com
            [cn] => Isaac Newton
        )
```

Essentially, my output currently is:

```
Name: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass
o
dc
Name: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass
cn
description
Name: uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com
sn
objectclass
uid
mail
cn
```

It should look like:

```
Name: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass:top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: example.com
dc: example

Name: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

Name: uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com
sn: Newton
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
uid: newton
mail: newton@ldap.forumsys.com
cn: Isaac Newton
```

Bonus points if you can make it into JSON & BSON as well since this will be used to add to MongoDB

Comment: Have you looked at `json_encode()`?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON format, as you have duplicate keys (objectclass).

Comment: The main reason for the question is to iterate through the array as that's my main concern currently. As for the JSON format, it would just look like this: "objectclass" : "{top, dcObject, person}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's only two levels, you could easily do 2 `foreach` loops:

```
<?php
$arr    =   [
    'dc=example,dc=com' => [
        
        'objectclass' => [
            'top',
            'dcObject',
            'organization'
        ],
        'o' => 'example.com',
        'dc' => 'example'
    ],
    'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' => [
        'objectclass' => [
            'simpleSecurityObject',
            'organizationalRole'
        ],
        'cn' => 'admin',
        'description' => 'LDAP administrator'
    ],
    'uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com' => [
        'sn' => 'Newton',
        'objectclass' => [
            'inetOrgPerson',
            'organizationalPerson',
            'person',
            'top'
        ],
        'uid' => 'newton',
        'mail' => 'newton@ldap.forumsys.com',
        'cn' => 'Isaac Newton'
    ]
];

foreach($arr as $name => $settings) {
    $new[]  =   PHP_EOL."Name: {$name}";
    foreach($settings as $k => $v) {
        $new[]  =   "{$k}: ".((is_array($v))? implode(PHP_EOL."{$k}: ", $v) : $v);
    }
}

print_r(trim(implode(PHP_EOL, $new)));
```

Would give you:

```
Name: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: example.com
dc: example

Name: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

Name: uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com
sn: Newton
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
uid: newton
mail: newton@ldap.forumsys.com
cn: Isaac Newton
```

As for the `json`, you probably could just use `json_encode($arr)` to make it json automatically (as noted in comments).